# Array of objects and toString

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, bluej

I'm gonna include what I got first.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Creates a class called presidents
public class presidents3{
    // Initilaizes an object called input using the Scanner that is public.
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Initializes a public static String variable called strInfo.
    public static String strInfo;
    // Initializes a public int variables number.
    public static int number;
    // Creates a main method that doesn't return anything.
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Initilaizes a String multidimensional array that holds the information about the presidents.
        String presidents[][] = {
        {"1 ","George"," ","Washington"," (1789-1797) ","John Adams"},
        {"2 ","John"," ","Adams"," (1797-1801) ","Thomas Jefferson"},
        {"3 ","Thomas"," ","Jefferson"," (1801-1809) ","Aaron Burr"},
        {"4 ","James"," ","Madison"," (1809-1817) ","George Clinton"},
        {"5 ","James"," ","Monroe"," (1817-1825) ","Daniel D. Tompkins"},
        {"6 ","John"," Quincy ","Adams"," (1825-1829) ","John C. Calhoun"},
        {"7 ","Andrew"," ","Jackson"," (1829-1837) ","John C. Calhoun"},
        {"8 ","Martin"," Van ","Buren"," (1837-1841) ","Richard M. Johnson"},
        {"9 ","William"," Henry ","Harrison"," (1841) ","John Tyler"},
        {"10 ","John"," ","Tyler"," (1841-1845) ","None"},
        {"11 ","James"," K. ","Polk"," (1845-1849) ","George M. Dallas"},
        {"12 ","Zachary"," ","Taylor"," (1849-1850) ","Millard Fillmore"},
        {"13 ","Millard"," ","Fillmore"," (1850-1853) ","None"},
        {"14 ","Franklin"," ","Pierce"," (1853-1857) ","William King"},
        {"15 ","James"," ","Buchanan"," (1857-1861) ","John C. Breckinridge"},
        {"16 ","Abraham"," ","Lincoln"," (1861-1865) ","Hannibal Hamlin"},
        {"17 ","Andrew"," ","Johnson"," (1865-1869) ","None"},
        {"18 ","Ulysses"," S. ","Grant"," (1869-1877) ","Schuyler Colfax"},
        {"19 ","Rutherford"," B. ","Hayes"," (1877-1881) ","William Wheeler"},
        {"20 ","James"," A. ","Garfield"," (1881) ","Chester Arthur"},
        {"21 ","Chester"," ","Arthur"," (1881-1885) ","None"},
        {"22 ","Grover"," ","Cleveland"," (1885-1889) ","Thomas Hendricks"},
        {"23 ","Benjamin"," ","Harrison"," (1889-1893) ","Levi P. Morton"},
        {"24 ","Grover"," ","Cleveland"," (1893-1897) ","Adlai E. Stevenson"},
        {"25 ","William"," ","McKinley"," (1897-1901) ","Garret Hobart"},
        {"26 ","Theodore"," ","Roosevelt"," (1901-1909) ","None"},
        {"27 ","William"," Howard ","Taft"," (1909-1913) ","James S. Sherman"},
        {"28 ","Woodrow"," ","Wilson"," (1913-1921) ","Thomas R. Marshall"},
        {"29 ","Warren"," G. ","Harding"," (1921-1923) ","Calvin Coolidge"},
        {"30 ","Calvin"," ","Coolidge"," (1923-1929) ","None"},
        {"31 ","Herbert"," ","Hoover"," (1929-1933) ","Charles Curtis"},
        {"32 ","Franklin"," D. ","Roosevelt"," (1933-1945) ","John Nance Garner"},
        {"33 ","Harry"," S. ","Truman"," (1945-1953) ","None"},
        {"34 ","Dwight"," D. ","Eisenhower"," (1953-1961) ","Richard Nixon"},
        {"35 ","John"," F. ","Kennedy"," (1961-1963) ","Lyndon B. Johnson"},
        {"36 ","Lyndon"," B. ","Johnson"," (1963-1969) ","None"},
        {"37 ","Richard"," ","Nixon"," (1969-1974) ","Spiro Agnew"},
        {"38 ","Gerald"," ","Ford"," (1974-1977) ","Nelson Rockefeller"},
        {"39 ","Jimmy"," ","Carter"," (1977-1981) ","Walter Mondale"},
        {"40 ","Ronald"," ","Reagan"," (1981-1989) ","George Bush"},
        {"41 ","George"," ","Bush"," (1989-1993) ","Dan Quayle"},
        {"42 ","Bill"," ","Clinton"," (1993-2001) ","Al Gore"},
        {"43 ","George"," W. ","Bush"," (2001-2009) ","Dick Cheney"},
        {"44 ","Barack"," ","Obama"," (2009-2017) ","Joe Biden"},
        };
        President[] President = new President[44];
        // Welcomes user and asks for input which will appear on the same line that asks for your input.
        System.out.println("This will display the President and VP of the United States based on the number you provide.");
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 44 to see information or q to quit: ");
        strInfo = input.nextLine();
        // Creates a while loop and checks if the strInfo equals q.
        while (!strInfo.equals("q")){
           // Calls the isInteger method and passes the strInfo and sees if strInfo can become an int.
           if (isInteger(strInfo)){
               // If the boolean is true, number will be set to Integer.parseInt(strInfo) which converts the String to int.
               number = Integer.parseInt(strInfo);
               if (number >= 1 && number <= 44){
                   // Prints out the information.
                   President President = new President ("1 ","George"," ","Washington"," (1789-1797) ","John Adams");
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println(Presidents.toString());
                   System.out.println();
                   // Asks for input once again
                   System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 44 to see information or q to quit: ");
                   strInfo = input.nextLine();
               }else{
                   // Asks for input once again when you have entered an invalid number.
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.print("Wrong Input! Please enter number 1-44 or q to quit: ");
                   strInfo = input.nextLine();
               }
           }else{
               // Asks for input once again when you have entered an invalid number and a String that is not q.
               System.out.println();
               System.out.print("Wrong Input! Please enter number 1-44 or q to quit: ");
               strInfo = input.nextLine();
           }
        }
        // Happens after you input q.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("This program has been terminated. Good Bye!");
    }

    // Creates a boolean method isInteger that takes the strInfo and checks if it can become an integer.
    public static boolean isInteger(String strInfo){
        // Attempts to convert strInfo to int and looks for something to catch. If it is null or not a number it will return false.
        try{ 
            Integer.parseInt(strInfo); 
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){ 
            return false; 
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            return false;
        }
        // If false wasn't returned at all during this method, true will be returned.
        return true;
    }
}
```

The other class:

```
public class President{
    String number;
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String lastName;
    String years;
    String vicePresident;

    public President(String num, String fName, String mName, String lName, String yrs, String vp){
        number = num;
        firstName = fName;
        middleName = mName;
        lastName = lName;
        years = yrs;
        vicePresident = vp;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Our %s was %s %s %s. /n He was in office from %s. /n His Vice President was %s.", this.number, this.firstName, this.middleName, this.lastName, this.years, this.vicePresident);
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do as part of a project. I was instructed to do it within two classes. I am trying to create an array of objects through a constructor that holds that information from the array of data that I have along with using the toString() method to properly format it to say the nth president was president. Then the years and then the vice president. I can describe it more upon request. I still need it to work off of input and still deny anything that is not 1-44 or "q". Does anyone have any ideas or know what it should look like or what I'm missing to make it work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the behavior that your current code produces?

Comment: Right now the second class does nothing but it currently accepts string input for displaying information about the Presidents along with q. I am trying to make an array of objects through another class along with using the toString() method to properly format it using the this keyword.

Comment: Why is everything in your code `static`?

Comment: I'm just more used to writing static. Is there actually any issue doing so? What would be the difference between me using `static` and me leaving `static` out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could create an array of object:

```
President[] presidents = new President[44];
```

Then pass the parameters.

```
presidents[0] = new President ("1 ","George"," ","Washington"," (1789-1797) ","John Adams");
```

OR you could do something like this :

```
 for(int i=0;i<44;i++){

       presidents = new President(YourString[i][0],YourString[i][1],YourString[i][2],YourString[i][3],YourString[i][4]);

 }
```

Comment: Which classes should your code at the top and the bottom go into?

Comment: Your main class. And also change the constructor method signature or the name of you second class to president

Comment: Ok. Where should I put in the for loop or what should the for loop replace?

Comment: Ok. Where should I put in the for loop or what should the for loop replace?

Comment: Sorry about the duplicates of the last two.

Comment: I have tried to implement both of those but it just gives me [LPresident;@28d272 for a location.

Comment: Also with the for loop it says that from this line: presidents = new President(presidents[i][0],presidents[i][1],presidents[i][2],presidents[i][3],presidents[i][4],presidents[i][5]); that Presidents cannot be converted to java.lang.String[][]

Comment: Did you add presidents like this : `President pr= new President ("1 ","George"," ","Washington"," (1789-1797) ","John Adams");`You must have been calling the string because you are using the name for your string and class `presidents`so change that and it should fix it.

Comment: How would I do that in the for loop?

Comment: Before making those changes, there was no problem with the toString() and now it says that it cannot be referenced from a static

Comment: I'h gonna edit what I have above to what I have now so that you can see what I currently have.